# No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'out'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I keep getting this error and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using an template so I can get in the dir bin the executable. The dir include the header files. The dir obj for the object files created and the src for the .c files.

**My makefile**

```
OBJ_dir = obj
INC_DIR = include
OBJECTS = main.o client.o private.o memory.o process.o proxy.o server.o
main.o = main.h memory-private.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h syscall.h unistd.h wait.h sysexits.h memory.h 
client.o = client.h
private.o = private.h
memory.o = memory.h memory_private.h
process.o = process.h
proxy.o = proxy.h
server.o = server.h
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall –I $(INC_DIR)
LIBS = -lm

out: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(addprefix $(OBJ_dir)/,$(OBJECTS)) -o bin/out $(LIBS)

%.o: src/%.c $($@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ_dir)/$@ -c $<

clean:
    rm –f *.o out
    rm –f out
```

Comment: `main.o =` The `=` needs to be `:` there and for the other dependency rules too.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues here.  It's probably a good idea to read at least the first few chapters of [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html) to understand how make and makefiles work.

Take this rule:

```
out: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(addprefix $(OBJ_dir)/,$(OBJECTS)) -o bin/out $(LIBS)
```

First, it's not right to list a different target than the file you actually build.  Here you told make you'd build a target named `out`, but your recipe actually builds a target named `bin/out`.  That's wrong.

Second, but similarly, it's not right to have your target depend on one set of prerequisites (the files defined by `$(OBJECTS)`) but then have the recipe of your rule use a completely different set of prerequisites (by adding a `$(OBJ_dir)/` prefix to all the files).

This tells make "please build files `main.o`, `client.o`, etc., but what my command will actually use is files `obj/main.o`, `obj/client.o`, etc.".  It doesn't make sense to tell make to build targets that you aren't going to actually use.

This should be:

```
bin/out: $(addprefix $(OBJ_dir)/,$(OBJECTS))
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

In general if you ever find yourself writing a recipe where you are modifying the automatic variables like `$@` or `$^` instead of using them as-is, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Next your pattern rule has other issues:

```
%.o: src/%.c $($@)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ_dir)/$@ -c $<
```

First, you cannot use automatic variables like `$@` in a prerequisite list.  Those values are only set when expanding the *recipe* of a rule.  They are not set (empty) when evaluating the prerequisite list.  So `$($@)` expands to the empty string here and does nothing.

Second you have the same problem as above where you are not creating `$@` you are creating `$(OBJ_dir)/$@` which is wrong.  You should write your rule like this:

```
$(OBJ_dir)/%.o: src/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

so that the target lists the file you want to build, and the recipe uses `$@` without modification.

As for your prerequisites, you should just create them directly rather than trying to use fancy variables (which can't work).  As the comment above suggests, just change:

```
proxy.o = proxy.h
```

to:

```
proxy.o : proxy.h
```

(and all the rest) and it will work.  Note, though, that make always builds the first explicit target it sees by default so you may have to re-arrange your makefile a little bit if you want `bin/out` to be the default target.